# Apeend all sublist to other dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, tibble

Table

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Gxe.png)

So i have perform kind of methods for append printed substring to new
list. But, the problem was
it only return last of substring.

My method was :

```
for (ix in 1:length(komentar_aja)){
myList <- list()
myList <- append(myList, print(komentar_aja[[ix]]$text))}
```

Any kind of suggestion ? At least, if you provide an example .. just add explanation of how it
runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializating the list in each iteration of the code.
Try with the following:

```
myList <- list()
for (ix in 1:length(komentar_aja)){
myList <- append(myList, print(komentar_aja[[ix]]$text))}
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `lapply` here

```
myList <- lapply(komentar_aja, "[[", "text")
```